# Add a new Item in connected scenario, Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to add an entity in connected scenario in entity framework. I can update a data, but for add and delete, it does not work in connected mode.

```
  md.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;  
  var studentList = md.MyStudent.ToList<Student>();
  studentList.Add(new Student { Stdname = "nm" });
  md.SaveChanges();
```

the new item ("nm") wont be added!!!

***EDITED***

Why Does this work , an update operation and Add does not work, what is the difference?

the database will be updated

```
 Student studentToUpdate = studentList.Where(s => s.Stdname == "stdname1").FirstOrDefault<Student>();
     studentToUpdate.Stdname = "Edited stdname3";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `md.MyStudent.Add()` method.

**A bit of explanation**

EF has a change tracking mechanism so that it can automatically persist the changes you make to your entities. However, EF has to know about your object/entity in order to be able to detect the changes.
In your second example EF knows about the student entity because it was created by the framework, you applied the `Where()` extension method on a `DbSet` instance which is part of the EF context.

In your first example you also retrieved the entities from a `DbSet`, however this time you applied the `ToList()` extension method, which creates a new `List<Student>` instance containing all the students stored in your database, but  EF doesn't have a reference to that list, only it knows about the entities in the list. As a result, if you add/remove items from that list EF won't know about your changes. You could still make changes to the entities in the list and get the modifications saved to the database.

Comment: thanks, I know this method, but what is the difference between this method and Disconnected mode, It seems Add() is not related to connected, it works in Disconnected mode either!! Am I right??

Comment: EF dowsn't know anything about your `studentList` variable. You cannot persist another `Student` object by adding it to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because your `ToList<Student>()` returns a new list unrelated to your context. This is similar to the following code:

```
IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
studentList.Add(new Student { Stdname = "nm" });
```

Your context from the entity framework don't care if you have a list *somewhere* in your program and add an object to it.

Editing existing objects in your list works because they were loaded from the context, therefore they are "registered" in the context.

If you want to add a new object you have to add it to `md.MyStudent` so the context sees that a new object should be added.